# How to write proxy rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, mod-proxy

I want to proxy all the CSS and JS files in a webpage.
For example, in a webpage `http://domain-a.com/myapp/somepage/` has some JS/CSS. I want to proxy all those CSS/JS to another domain let's say `http://domain-b.com`.
So, the goal is that `http://domain-a.com/myapp/somepage/static/jsfiles/somejsfile.js` should be proxied to `http://domain-b.com/jsfiles/somejsfile.js`
That means, whatever comes after `/myapp/somepage/static/`, should be rewritten and proxied to `http://domain-b.com/jsfiles/somejsfile.js`.

I have tried the following but it does not work.

```
RewriteRule ^/myapp/somepage/static/?.*$ http://domain-b.com$0 [P]
```

When I open this url `http://domain-a.com/myapp/somepage/static/jsfiles/somejsfile.js` then I expect that js file to be downloaded from `domain-b.com` using proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteRule ^/?myapp/somepage/static/(.*) http://domain-b.com/$1 [P]
```

If you only want to proxy `.css` and `.js` files (if you have other file types that should not be proxied) then use a more restrictive regex to target just those file types. eg. `...static/(.+\.(css|js))$`

Comment: Thanks for your help. For CSS files I get this error "Rrefused to apply style from mime type strict mime checking is enabled" for domain-a and for JS files, it shows 404. Propably in this case ProxyHTMLEnable needs to be used?

Comment: @Learner That would imply the target server is returning an incorrect `Content-Type` header as part of the response (or it is being stripped/changed by the proxy). You should see `Content-Type: text/css` in the HTTP response. You do need to make sure all the necessary mod_proxy (and related) modules are installed on the server (`domain-a.com`).

Comment: mod_proxy is installed but I am not sure do I need to install mod_proxy_html? do you think 404 error for JS files, is also because of incorrect header or something else?

Comment: @Learner You probably don't need mod_proxy_html in this case. Regarding the 404 for JS files... not sure, other than the URL is incorrect and/or the file does not exist??